# Github to vercel deployment, all check failed

Tags: git, github, deployment, vercel

When I push changes to all of my github repo. It is supposed to trigger deployments(it was triggering before). But the last few commits is showing me error "All checks failed".

When I commit new commits to my github repo it is showing me below error.

[image]

All of my commits were triggering deployment however, last few commits started to show my above error. The vercel deployment tab does not show any logs. I see this error on github. That is the only thing I get. Any idea what could have possibly gone wrong?

BTW I was making too many commits since morning in quick succession. I checked the limitation where I could not find any per day or per hour limitations on vercel docs.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you if you don't provide any details!

You should open your project in your Vercel dashboard, find the failing deployment, and the explanation should be in the log. Please paste it here if you don't understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue had to do with settings in the "vercel.json". I had max duration for serverless function too high and only found it when trying to redeploy. Once I fixed that my commits started to deploy.